# poetry's 'run' stopped working claiming manage.py is missing

Tags: django, shell, python-poetry

I have been using the *run* command for a year to perform all kinds of admin work, in this precise manner (i.e. with a dot):

```
poetry run ./manage.py runserver
```

and suddenly it no longer works, saying:

```
$ poetry run ./manage.py runserver
Command not found: ./manage.py
```

But the file is there, and is executable:

```
$ file manage.py
manage.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

with a proper #! /usr/bin/env python

I know there's another way, namely:

> $ poetry shell

followed by

> $ ./manage.py runserver

but I feel a little stupid having to work around it =)

I have recreated the virtual environment, but to no avail. The problem must be somewhere else, is my shell is missing something or poetry's setup? I did reinstall the system after all, but that wasn't a first time of so doing..

:::edited:::

this also works, which is less of a workaround:

> poetry run python manage.py check

, but the mystery of the old command stopping to work remains

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What version of Poetry are you using? Have you updated it recently?

Comment: version 1.5.0; and yes I probably did. Strange that I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to 1.5.1 should solve your problem. This release contains https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/7963